# Is it allowed to make an onClick listener of an item in RecyclerView act on a local variable that is instantiated during onBindViewHolder?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am not sure if this is allowed or it will sometimes make the unintended item used.

So let's say I have a fixed data:

```
final String[] items = {"a", "b", "c"};
```

My RecyclerView adapter has number of items equal to that data size:

```
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return items.size();
}
```

Then I bind the data and also set an onClickListener:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final String item = items[position];
    holder.textView.setText(item);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> Log.d(TAG, "Item " + item + " was clicked!"); // 1
}
```

My question is whether the line marked `// 1` is correct. Or do I have to do this instead?

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> Log.d(TAG, "Item " + items[holder.getAdapterPosition()] + " was clicked!");
```

Comment: It is nice if you implement the `OnClickListener` in the Adapter itself and use `holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(this)` the reason is performance.

Comment: I see no problem with line marked `// 1`

Comment: @Enzokie if I implement it on the adapter how do I know the position?

Comment: If you look at the onClick it returns a `view` instance (Thats itemView actually in your case!). The view can hold an object and it has setters and getters method e.g. `setTag` and `getTag` if you want I can help you through Teamviewer.

Comment: @Enzokie how does using setTag and getTag to know the view position have better performance than setting an onClickListener as anonymous class instance like the example above?

Comment: @yuku you can pass a number to `setTag`, and recover it using `getTag` then use that as query to your array. Other thing than that you can pass the object itself and manipulate it. I can demonstrate it if you have Teamviewer and explain how this works and why should I use it instead.

Comment: @Enzokie passing a number to setTag requires an object allocation, and setting an onClickListener as anonymous class instance like the example above also needs an object allocation. I guess that's the same performance hit?

Comment: @yuku In your approach when `onBindViewHolder` is called it will also create an `anonymous instance of the OnClickListener`(Which means an Object creation). While the users `flings` the device the onBindViewHolder is also called, "What if the user flings it insanely?" For sure there will be too many anonymous object that are being created. While the approach for referencing the the object into a pointer will lessen the issue since there is no creation happen. You wont feel the performance benefit from High core devices but on lower spec device you will see some super slowness.

Comment: @Enzokie Yeah but then if let's say you put setTag(position), it also creates an Integer object (hmm, may not always be the case, since small integers are cached). Is that your point?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120231/discussion-between-enzokie-and-yuku).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [official onBindViewHolder docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)):

> Note that unlike ListView, RecyclerView will not call this method again if the position of the item changes in the data set unless the item itself is invalidated or the new position cannot be determined. For this reason, you should only use the position parameter while acquiring the related data item inside this method and should not keep a copy of it. If you need the position of an item later on (e.g. in a click listener), use getAdapterPosition() which will have the updated adapter position.

According to this description, in an `OnClickListener` it is better to use `getAdapterPosition()` since the position of an item may change at runtime. Anyway, they recommend to use `getAdapterPosition()` when you need the value "later" (like in an `OnClickListener`), so this probably is the way to go.